# Why my "soupRequest" is being reset to initial value and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first contact with React and also my first question on Stack so please be patient.

I have a clean `App.jsx` that renders the parent component `Lettersoup`.

> **App.jsx**

```
import './assets/CSS/App.css';
import LetterSoup from './components/LetterSoup';

function App() {

    return ( 
        <div className="app_container">
            <LetterSoup />
        </div>);

}
export default App;
```

The app has a parent `Lettersoup`, that calls `controlpanel`, `grid` and `words` components. The one pertinent for this issue is `controlpanel`. I will comment out the divs for `grid` and `words` as they are working and are not needed for resolving this issue.

On `Lettersoup` there is the base layout and logic...

> **Lettersoup.jsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import ControlPanel from '../components/ControlPanel';
import Grid from '../components/Grid';
import Words from '../components/Words';

function LetterSoup() {

    const [soupRequest, setsoupRequest] = useState(null);
    const [letterSoup, setletterSoup] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setisLooading] = useState(true);
    const childToParent = (childdata) => {
        console.log("CLICK");
        setsoupRequest(childdata);
    }
    const contents = isLoading == true
        ? <p>Loading...</p>
        :
        <div className="lettersoup_container">
            <h1 id="tabelLabel">Sopa de letras (PT)</h1>
            <div className="controlpanel_container">
                {soupRequest && <ControlPanel soupRequest={soupRequest} childToParent={childToParent} />}
            </div>
            <div>
                {letterSoup.wordsNum} palavras
            </div>
/*          <div className="grid_container">
                <Grid board={letterSoup.board} />
            </div>
            <div className="words_container">
                <Words words={letterSoup.words} />
            </div>
*/
        </div>;

    useEffect(() => {
        let ignore = false;
        async function fetchData(sr) {
            let aux;
            console.log("REQ " + JSON.stringify(sr));
            if (sr == null) {
                aux = (`/lettersoup/15/10/4`);
                sr = ({ gridNum: 15, wordNum: 10, charNum: 4 });
                setsoupRequest(sr);
                console.log("need new");
            }
            else {
                aux = (`/lettersoup/${sr.gridNum}/${sr.wordNum}/${sr.charNum}`);
                console.log("had one");
            }

            try {
                const response = await fetch(aux);
                if (!ignore)
                    if (response.ok) {
                        const data = await response.json();
                        setletterSoup(data);
                        setisLooading(false);
                    } else throw Error("nao é ok");
            }
            catch {
                console.log(error.message)
            }
        }
        fetchData(soupRequest);

        return () => {
            //cleanup
            ignore = true
            setisLooading(true);
        };
    }, [soupRequest]);

    return (<div>{contents}</div>);
}

export default LetterSoup;
```

The second on has the controls to change the parameters for a subsequent API fetch for rendering.

> **Controlpanel.jsx**

```
import { useId, useState } from 'react';

function ControlPanel({ soupRequest, childToParent }) {

    const inputId = useId();
    const [tmpRequest, setmpRequest] = useState(soupRequest);


    return (
        <form className="controlpanel">
            <div className="controlpanel_settings">
                <div className="controlapanel_setting"><label htmlFor={inputId}>Tamanho da grelha</label>
                    <input type="number" value={tmpRequest.gridNum} min="10" max="25" step="5" id={inputId} name="gridNum" onChange={event => setmpRequest({ gridNum: parseInt(event.target.value), wordNum: parseInt(tmpRequest.wordNum), charNum: parseInt(tmpRequest.charNum) })} className="controlpanel_setting_input" />

                </div>
                <div className="controlapanel_setting"><label htmlFor={inputId + 1}>Número de palavras</label>
                    <input type="number" value={tmpRequest.wordNum} min="10" max="50" step="1" id={inputId + 1} name="wordNum" onChange={event => setmpRequest({ gridNum: parseInt(tmpRequest.gridNum), wordNum: parseInt(event.target.value), charNum: parseInt(tmpRequest.charNum) })} className="controlpanel_setting_input" />
                </div>
                <div className="controlapanel_setting"><label htmlFor={inputId + 2}>Mínimo de letras</label>
                    <input type="number" value={tmpRequest.charNum} min="3" max="20" step="1" id={inputId + 2} name="charNum" onChange={event => setmpRequest({ gridNum: parseInt(tmpRequest.gridNum), wordNum: parseInt(tmpRequest.wordNum), charNum: parseInt(event.target.value) })} className="controlpanel_setting_input" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="controlpanel_button">
                <button onClick={() => { childToParent(tmpRequest); }}>GO</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}

export default ControlPanel;
```

I can get the updated value `soupRequest` on the parent sent from the child but as soon as *useEffect * runs, the `soupRequest` gets set to `null`, thus rendering the default values over and over.

What I would expect is that the `soupRequest` sent from the `controlpanel` component to persist, allowing me to make the fetch of the correct resource. If it was working the inputs on `controlpanel` would keep the values previously set instead of the default ones.

I've read and tried many things, including `useRefs` etc, although I love the learning journey I have read a lot and still am stuck, would like to move on and learn other things. Almost certainly this is one of those problems that you guys laugh about and solve in a blink or would not even experience, but please, give me a push.

Hopefully I am providing the code and explanation needed. Let me know if not and I'll will improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ControlPanel` component renders a `form` element and the `button` element you are using to call the callback also submits the form, and since you are not preventing the default form action from occurring, the page is reloaded, thus the entire app and `LetterSoup` are remounted with their initial state values.

HTML `button` elements use `type="submit"` by default when not specified.

Either specify the button to be anything but a submit button:

```
function ControlPanel({ soupRequest, childToParent }) {
  const inputId = useId();
  const [tmpRequest, setmpRequest] = useState(soupRequest);

  return (
    <form className="controlpanel">
      ...
      <div className="controlpanel_button">
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => childToParent(tmpRequest)}
        >
          GO
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Or move the `childToParent` call to the `form` element's `onSubmit` prop and prevent the form submission:

```
function ControlPanel({ soupRequest, childToParent }) {
  const inputId = useId();
  const [tmpRequest, setmpRequest] = useState(soupRequest);

  return (
    <form
      className="controlpanel"
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent form action
        childToParent(tmpRequest);
      }}
    >
      ...
      <div className="controlpanel_button">
        <button type="submit">
          GO
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

You'll want to get in the habit of *always* explicitly passing a `type` prop on `button` elements.

Comment: Drew = "life saver'. I feel even more stupid now. there I was thinking the problem was on my nonexistent skills on react and that was it. I had tried with "preventdefault" before but to no avail. Your explanation and code are spot on. I found it strange to see the page doing full reload but never crossed my mind. For future reference which is the most elegant way to do things? I chose the "form" one, although it has more code, to keep it as a learning example.

Comment: @RuiRodrigues I prefer `form` elements having an `onSubmit` handler since it makes intent more obvious, but this is subjective. Use what makes sense and is easier for you to work with and maintain.